# TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout

Tags: .net, sql-server, exception, timeout

I am getting the below error in my .net application.

```
>System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

I checked similar questions in the forum and most of the response/answer is to increase/set a time out period greater than the default time out.
That helps with some slow transactions/db operations.

Increasing the time out to doesn't really help to find out the exact problem right?

I have noticed that no errors are logged in the SQL server which supports this application.Users do lots of read operations in this application. And since I don't see any SQL Server logs for query timing out, I assume that it is not something related to SQL Server.

The users are connected over the network.If it is an error with table locks ,i  think i will get an error number,severity also in the SQL server logs,i believe.Also i have extended event session running to capture all sql server errors and i don't see this error in there.Its confusing to me that it is a sql error or some application code issue.

How can I find out the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you.

This happened to me once, the query which was running every 5 mins on schedule for a year or so suddenly started timing out. The issue was there were lot of people who opened the connection using Assistants like Dbeaver, teradata sql assistant and other IDE's. Contacted the DB Admin to remove their connection and it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

check the sql server logs for disconnected sessions. are you connected over networked.
other issue could be locked tables when other complex queries are locking the tables your trying to update.

Comment: yes,the users are connected over the network.If it is an error with table locks ,i  think i will get an error number,severity also in the SQL server logs,i believe.Also i have extended event session running to capture all sql server errors and i don't see this error in there.Its confusing to me that it is a sql error or some application code issue.